# Sort NSDictornary with numbers as the key value

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` of `mutableArrays` as objects; and numbers for the key value.

I want to sort the `dictionary`.

```
NSArray *sortedDict = [[NSArray alloc] init];
sortedDict = [self.myDict keysSortedByValuesUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

NSLog(@"%@", sortedDict);
```

When I run the app, it crashes with the following error:

```
'-[__NSArrayM compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9202f2ce50
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's the wrong method. That sorts the values (your arrays) and gives back the keys in the corresponding order. Just sort the keys with no regard to the values.

Comment: How should I sort the keys with no regard to the values?

Comment: Get the keys array. Sort it.

Comment: But then I won't have the  values in the array?

Comment: You access the values as needed using the sorted keys. Remember, a dictionary can't be sorted. You can sort the keys array or you can sort the values array but you can't sort the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message gives a strong hint of what's going wrong:

```
[__NSArrayM compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9202f2ce50
```

It tells you that there was an attempt to call the `compare:` method on an array (a mutable array, to be precise). Your dictionary has `NSNumber`s for keys, and arrays for values, so the attempt has been made to compare values, not keys!

That makes perfect sense: the method name tells you that it is going to compare values, not keys:

```
keysSortedByValuesUsingSelector
            ^^^^^^
```

If you would like to sort values by keys, retrieve all keys, sort them, and then retrieve the corresponding values in the sorted order of keys:

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [myDict.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSMutableArray *sortedVals = [dict objectsForKeys:sortedKeys notFoundMarker:nil];
```

At this point you have two arrays with one-for-one correspondence between them: `sortedKeys` has the keys, and `sortedVals` has the values.